# Centering div with flex

Tags: css, flexbox

So, I am using following css to align a div container in the center of the page

```
<div class="flex-container">
    <div class="conatiner"> 
       Something centered
    </div>
</div>   

.flex-container{
 text-align: center;
 display: flex;
 height: 100%;
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
 display: -webkit-box;
 display: -moz-box;
 display: -ms-flexbox;
 display: -webkit-flex;
 display: flex;
 align-items: center;
 justify-content: center;
 text-align: center;
}
  .conatiner{
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #fafafa;
  text-align: left;
}
```

Here is [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3ouqgbs0/).

As you can see, the inner container starts from the width of 50% mark.

How do I change it so that the container (regardless of its width) is always centered of the page using flex?

Thanks

Comment: Your `.container` is not centered in the fiddle because you misspelled the class name in your CSS. Fix it and it will work.

Comment: Here is an updated class time (https://jsfiddle.net/3ouqgbs0/1/). There was no spelling mistake. And unfortunately I need to use the position:absoulte.

Comment: Here's your working [(intial) fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3ouqgbs0/2/). If you **need** to use `position:absolute`, you are taking the element out of the document flow, effectively  removing the `flex` from it. So the absolute positioned element doesn't have anything to do with flex anymore, you need to use box model centering method, suggested in LOTUSMS's solution.

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu I added this explanation to the answer ::Beers::

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correction noted by Andrei...Thanks bud

```
.conatiner {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #fafafa;
  text-align: left;
  left: 50%; 
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

Quoting [**Andrei**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1891677/andrei-gheorghiu)

> "If you need to use position:absolute, you are taking the element out of the document flow, effectively removing the flex from it. So the absolute positioned element doesn't have anything to do with flex anymore, you need to use box model centering method"

See the [**DEMO**](http://codepen.io/LOTUSMS/pen/qbjEQK)

Comment: This solution will not work on elements with dynamic length. You should use `{left: 50%; transform: translateX(-50%);}`

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu You are correct Andrei. I didn't think about that posibility. Add you answer. I'll delete mine. I added it to the codepen I gave him, use that same link

Comment: OP is claiming there was no spelling mistake. I suppose the answer can stay then? I did notice the class was awefully closely named to container. But it matched the HTML and CSS so that threw me off too.

Comment: Thank @AndreiGheorghiu for that one steve. He caught it. I originally thought you were centering a small label judging by what you had in your fiddle.

Comment: Everyone learned something here. We're all good. See my explanation on positioning under question, @steveKim.

Comment: mhmm! =) Thanks everyone!